# Are all theorems usable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, big-picture

The (revised) question to answer:

> Can anyone give an example of a serious proof using this funny (revised) theorem?
>
> For any natural number $n$ and prime $p<n-1$ there exist a prime $q$ so that $n\equiv p\pmod q$

(The theorem has a very easy proof).

With a serious proof one could mean a proof where the theorem is needed for the construction and the idea of the proof.

The question might seem awkward, but arise from a wonder about mathematics in a future when computers might generate millions of maybe easy-proved but somewhat non intuitive theorems. Could such theorems, which not are the result of the intuition of mathematicians, be of any importance?

Comment: How about Euclid's simple proof of the infinitude of primes?  Where are the engineering applications of the fact that that is true, as opposed to the number of primes being far beyond any number that humans will ever think about? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. Of course there are useful theorems easy to prove. And that theorem is a fruit of mathematical intuition indeed.

Comment: @Lehs I think it's possible to get computers to make guesses as to which theorems are interesting and which are not.  For example, your theorem that you stated is an "existence theorem", but a simple proof of it is $p=2$ and $q|n-2$, so this doesn't generate any _new_ primes.  A computer may be able to recognize its triviality, and know not to notify any humans.  That's just my thoughts.

Comment: You may also want to better define the term "serious." What exactly constitutes a serious vs. a not-so-serious proof?

Comment: @JasonM, what if $n-2$ is a prime?

Comment: @Lehs No difference: $n-2 \mid n-2$.

Comment: @Lehs Then $q=n-2$.  Is that a problem?

Comment: @JasonM. No! That was a proof taking all shining away.

Comment: A slighly harder version is: for every integer $n$ and prime $q$ there is a prime $p$ so that $n\equiv p\bmod q$. corollary of dirichlet's theorem and the fact that $q$ is a prime.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling. Can I borrow your theorem, also easy to prove, to enhance my question?

Comment: The theorem that CarryonSmiling mentioned is actually a bit more difficult..

Comment: @Ravi. I didn't mean the theorem of Dirichlet, but his slightly harder version of my theorem. Which is also easy to prove.

Comment: Importance is not an internal property of anything. Nothing is important. It is us who make it important. Could the computer-found theorems be of importance? Sure, they could be. Will they? Who knows. You might also be interested in [this shameless self-promotion](http://karagila.org/2016/some-thoughts-about-automated-theorem-searching/) of my blog from a couple weeks ago.

Comment: @Lehs for sure, although it isn't mine.